# Bootstrap carousel with multiple items per slide and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap to display a carousel on my website, and I display several items per slide following [this example](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/zDQkr). Using static images works perfectly well and I'm very happy about the results (example on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0L21xotc/), **make sure the display frame is big enough to avoid a strange effect due to boostrap's media queries, which I will take care of later**).

However now, I would like to define the content of the carousel from a variable and bind it with AngularJS with a `ng-repeat`. That's where a problem occurs. The data is binded properly, but only the image considered as the "active" item displays. I understand that it makes sense, but it wasn't behaving like that with statically defined images. See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmbvm7hq/) to see my bug.

What I tried so far :

- Display all items and set overflow:hidden
- Change the items size to 33% and display everything, instead of using the class col-md-4

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel-started-themes" style="height:150px; width:700px;">
  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="img in image">
        <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img ng-src="{{img}}" class="img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" style="z-index:10000;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" style="z-index:10000;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.image =["https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/minimalism_sky_clouds_sun_mountains_lake_landscape_95458_1600x900.jpg", "https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/clouds_milky_way_eclipse_light_68883_1600x900.jpg", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSl5bsNT-Qtm0tfbydXFMuFCG27Kug6D5Z3hrgitIQqQq22Da95Ig", "https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Photos-1600x900-Wallpapers-HD.jpg", "https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/torzhok_tver_region_evening_sunset_river_reflection_autumn_russia_58028_1600x900.jpg", "https://wallpaper.wiki/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/wallpaper.wiki-1600x900-HD-Image-PIC-WPD0014727.jpg"];
}

$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function() {
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length > 0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The problem was that jQuery was executing too fast, not waiting for ng-repeat to be finished before binding the data and adding the elements for multiple display.

I used [the following callback directive](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/ZFp3a/) to solve the problem, and called the jQuery methods inside the callback function.

**The directive:**

```
app.directive("repeatEnd", function(){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                if (scope.$last) {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.repeatEnd);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

This doesn't solve everything. There is still a problem with Angular binding not being applied since the elements are binded after the repeat is over. To work around this problem, I changed the jQuery code to get the index of the current element in the ng-repeat, and call my data from the index:

```
$scope.repeatOver = function(){

        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
          interval: false
        });

        $('.carousel .item').each(function(index){
          var next = $(this).next();
          var indexNext = index+1;
          var indexNextNext = index+2;
          if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
            indexNext = 0;
            indexNextNext = 1;
          }
          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
          // Change the source of the element
          $(this).children(':first-child').next()[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = $scope.image[indexNext];

          if (next.next().length>0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            // Change the source of the element
            $(this).children(':first-child').next().next()[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = $scope.image[indexNextNext];
          }
          else {
            indexNextNext = 0;
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
            // Change the source of the element
            $(this).children(':first-child').next().next()[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = $scope.image[indexNextNext];
          }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to show/hide at all? perhaps you could just use overflow:hidden; and and just use jquery to scroll left and right without a scroll bar. That way, there would never be a hide condition.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, because I don't "show or hide" anything, the active status of items is native to Bootstrap's carousel. I tried manually displaying everything and overflow:hidden; but the behaviour was roughly the same, unfortunately.